# How to access SIM contacts in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I need to access contact list in blackberry, I writ following code to do that:

```
private void readContacts() {
        try {
            PIM pim;
            pim = PIM.getInstance();
            String lists[] = pim.listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);

            for (int i = 0; i < lists.length ; i++) {
                clist = (ContactList) pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST,
                        PIM.READ_ONLY, lists[i]);

                Enumeration cenum = clist.items();
                while (cenum.hasMoreElements()) {
                    Contact c = (Contact) cenum.nextElement();
                    ContactDTO contact = new ContactDTO();
                    parseContactInfo(c, contact);
                    contacts.addElement(contact);
                }
                clist.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

In j2me this code access both sim and phone contacts but in blackberry it is accessing only phone contacts.

```
String lists[] = pim.listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);
```

`lists.length` return 1

How I can access sim contacts in blackberry??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post from Simon Hain](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-get-Sim-contacts-and-phone-contacts/td-p/1147369), you can't:

> you cannot access contacts from the sim card afaik. contacts from the
>   addressbook can be accessed with the PIM API, check
>   http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/pdap/BlackBerryContactList.html

That answer was circa OS 6.0, so perhaps something that I'm not aware of got added in OS 7 (?)