# How to get sim contacts information programmatically on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I got the BlackBerryContactList programmatically..

Now I want to get sim contacts infomation programmatically..

is it possible on blackberry.?

if possible means, how to get sim cantacts information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access SIM contacts in Blackberry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061158/how-to-access-sim-contacts-in-blackberry)

Comment: Short answer is that you can't (see the link to the duplicate question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no API in BlackBerry Java SDK to obtain SIM Card contacts.

The most recent java SDK version (version 7) provides only [SimCardInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SIMCardInfo.html) class with `getIMSI` method inside. But it retrieves the International Mobile Subscriber Identity number. And sim card contacts are not available.